# Chemmacros - redox module: cannot get the manual example to work

Tags: chemmacros

This is very likely a very dumb question. Please embarrass me. :-)

I enjoy using the `chemmacros` package tremendously. But I just don't seem to be able to get the `\redox` module work for me.

The PDF looks alright during the compiling but finishes wrong. There will be no overhead bridging at all, just a short vertical stick/arrow at the end of the equation, with "oxidation" above it.

I suspect `\redox` can't find the nodes defined by `\OX` but I just don't see why.

Here's the Minimum non-Working Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\vspace{7mm}
\OX{a,Na} $\rightarrow$ \OX{b,Na}\pch\redox(a,b){oxidation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example compiles without errors on my computer, and maybe the output is wrong but I don't know what it should look like. Maybe you could add a picture of the intended output?

Comment: Thanks Vincent for trying to help me! I've added my result. I said that I suspected the ```\redox``` cannot find the nodes defined. But on second thought, that can't be the case as the PDF temporarily looked correct during compiling (I use SumatraPDF for viewing). Just that the final result came out wrong.

Comment: I got a different output (a line going up from "Na", then right with "oxidation" written on top, then down to "Na+"). Are you sure your TeX distribution is up to date?

Comment: texlive = 2022. vscode. texworkshop. lualatex.

Comment: I reinstalled the texlive 2022, took nearly 6 hours but it solved a couple of problems.

I also realised that the ```siunitx``` package ```font-family = \sffamily``` option is also contributing to the same problem, when the chemical equation is complicated. When I unchecked it, not only did I get the ```\redox``` working, I got the sorrily missed ```\tableofcontents``` back too!

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
    \OX{a,Na} $\rightarrow$ \OX{b,Na}\pch\redox(a,b)[blue,-stealth]{oxidation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One more complete code

```
\documentclass[margin={1mm 7mm}, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}

\begin{document}
 \ch{2 "\OX{o1,\ox*{0,Na}}" + "\OX{r1,\ox*{0,Cl}}" {}2
    -> 2 "\OX{o2,\ox*{+1,Na}}" {}+ + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox*{-1,Cl}}" {}-}
\redox(o1,o2)[green,-stealth]{\small OX}
\redox(r1,r2)[purple,-stealth][-1]{\small RED}
\end{document}
```

[image]